# I can't ping my bond interface when simulating 2 WAN connections

Tags: networking, bonding

I'm actually simulating 2 WANs connexions with Wanem (each one on a different VM), those are connected to my servers.

What I need to do here is to create a bonding to improve my bandwidth. I've followed some tutorials, but when I set a configuration to bond0 interface, I can't ping it from the other side. I should also say that I made static routes on each device. I would be glad if someone can help!
[image]

EDIT : Followed Tutorial http://simonmott.co.uk/vpn-bonding

Comment: I am looking at your diagram but I cannot see where your bonding interface would be. Is it between one of the servers (Siege or Agence) and its adjacent router (R1,R2,R3,R4)? Please draw the bonding interface as a double line or something like that.

Comment: Bonding is between 172.16.10.1 and 172.16.1.1 (same for 172.16.2.1 and 172.16.20.1)

Comment: But those aren't even on the same layer 3 subnet. I don't think that makes any sense. Actually someone just answered you to say the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonding is not suited for such configuration. It is meant to be used on the same subnet.
You probably could use ECMP (Equal Cost MultiPath) routing to achieve what you want.

Some [ECMP tutorial](http://etutorials.org/Networking/Integrated+cisco+and+unix+network+architectures/Chapter+8.+Static+Routing+Concepts/Lab+8-1+Interface+Metrics+Floating+Static+Routes+and+Multiple+Equal-Cost+Routes+ECMP/)

Your tutorial suggest creating a VPN through each of the WANs and bonding those VPNs. That is possible as well, though I'd say it's kind of ugly.

To do that, you have to create VPN from 172.16.10.1 to 172.16.20.1 (tun0 in your tutorial) and VPN from 172.16.1.1 to 172.16.2.1 (tun1). Tutorial uses ssh to do that. Then you bond tun0 and tun1 to create bond0, which aggregates both links.
For best results you should bond the devices on both sides (actually I am not sure how that'd work without bonding on the other side).

Comment: Can you please give an exemple of a configuration close to mine in wich i can use bonding ?

Comment: @BadrOyd If you have two links between Siege and R1 for example, you can get 2Gbps instead of 1Gbps using bonding (assuming both links are 1Gbps).

Comment: I added a link to an ECMP tutorial. It could hint you in what you have to do.

Comment: @Celada Oh i understand now, that's what i was doing on the first place, i think that i misunderstood the tutorial that i was following