# Addresses overlaps

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet

I was putting somes static addresses to my interfaces then it shows me this:

```
172.16.1.0 overlaps with FastEthernet 0/0
```

What does it mean when two addresses overlaps and how can we avoid it?

**EDIT:** The problem happens on the router (on Ubuntu server everything works well)

[image: network scenario]

Comment: can you provides us with result of `netstat -in` and/or `ifconfig -a` ?

Comment: I've added an edit, hope it can clarify my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you are using the **same IP range** on both interfaces, or **overlapping IP ranges**.

For example:

```
Interface     IP Address         Subnet Mask
eth0         192.168.2.10     255.255.255.240
eth1         192.168.2.2      255.255.255.252
```

It causes an overlapping because, according to the subnet mask:

1. *eth0* is in the range `192.168.2.0 - 192.168.2.15`
2. *eth1* is in the range `192.168.2.0 - 192.168.2.3`

The range of *eth1* is contained inside the range of *eth0*.

Comment: So it's impossible for me to put eth0 and eth1 on the same subnet ?

Comment: It's impossible. The router creates its routing table based on the subnet ranges, so an overlapping cause a routing table conflict. Are you looking for **interface bonding**?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to make an interface bonding by putting eth0 and eth1 on the same subnet

Comment: Even as *Ubuntu* seems to be not having problems, only one of both interfaces is doing ARP, and all the traffic is going through one of them.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196620/i-cant-ping-my-bond-interface-when-simulating-2-wan-connections , Celada said on comments that they should be on the same layer 3 subnet. I'm really confused

Comment: Check your router vendor configuration manual. There is a way to make **interface bonding** but I think that it involves using a *"virtual"* IP address for both interfaces.

Comment: Actually i'm just trying to make a simulation on GNS3..

Comment: When you said that for **Ubuntu** only one of both interfaces is doing ARP, i think that can be solved by adding new routes on routing table, I'm I wrong ?

Comment: I haven't done that kind of configuration. The theory says that is its no feasible,